# Rails: system process won't start in rails server, but will in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to start a **ngrok** process when server starts. To achieve this, I coded a ngrok.rb lib and I call it within an initializer

*app/lib/ngrok.rb*

```
require "singleton"
class Ngrok
    include Singleton

    attr_accessor :api_url, :front_url


    def start
        if is_running?
            return fetch_urls
        end

        authenticate
        started = system("ngrok start --all -log=stdout > #{ENV['APP_ROOT']}/log/ngrok.log &")
        system("sleep 1")
        if !started
            return { api: nil, front: nil }
        end

        urls = fetch_urls
        sync_urls(urls["api_url"], urls["front_url"])
        return urls
    end

    def sync_urls(api_url, front_url)
        NgrokSyncJob.perform_later(api_url, front_url)
    end

    def is_running?
        return system("ps aux | grep ngrok")
    end
    def restart
        stop
        return start
    end
    def stop
        return system("pkill ngrok")
    end

    def authenticate
        has_file = system("ls ~/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml")
        if has_file
            return true
        else
            file_created = system("ngrok authtoken #{ENV['NGROK_TOKEN']}")
            if file_created
                return system("cat " + ENV['APP_ROOT'] + '/essentials/ngrok/example.yml >> ~/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml')
            else
                return false
            end
        end
    end

    def fetch_urls
        logfile = ENV['APP_ROOT'] + '/log/ngrok.log'

        file = File.open logfile
        text = file.read

        api_url = nil
        front_url = nil

        text.split("\n").each do |line|
            next if !line.include?("url=") || !line.include?("https")

            if line.split("name=")[1].split(" addr=")[0] == "ncommerce-api"
                api_url = line.split("url=")[1]
            elsif line.split("name=")[1].split(" addr=")[0] == "ncommerce"
                front_url = line.split("url=")[1]
            end
        end

        file.close

        self.api_url = api_url
        self.front_url = front_url

        res = {}
        res["api_url"] = api_url
        res["front_url"] = front_url

        return res
    end
end
```

*config/initializers/app-init.rb*

```
module AppModule
    class Application < Rails::Application
        config.after_initialize do
            puts "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            Ngrok.instance.start
            puts "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

        end
    end
end
```

When I type **rails serve**, here is a sample of the output

[image]

So we know for sure my initializer is being called, but when I look at rails console if it's running, **it's not!**

[image]

But when I type `Ngrok.instance.start` in rails console, here's the output:

[image]

And it starts!

[image]

So, my question is: WHY ON EARTH is `system("ngrok start --all -log=stdout > #{ENV['APP_ROOT']}/log/ngrok.log &")` NOT working on rails serve, but it is on rails console?

**UPDATE**

If I use 'byebug' within ngrok.rb and use rails serve, when I exit byebug with "continue", the ngrok process is created and works

Comment: The fact that it works when you put a breakpoint makes me think it's an issue of timing between async processes. Mess around with adding some more sleep and see if that changes anything

Comment: @maxpleaner sure. That's what I thought. I've put countless sleeps at countless places! Still I don't think that's the issue since Ngrok.instance.start worked in rails c but not in rails s, regardless of the inner sleeps

Comment: Are you running on macOS or Linux or else?

Comment: You don't have any error checking. Use `exception: true` or child_process or manual fork+exec with error checking.

Comment: @kisch I'm running Linux, Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an *orphaned process* in the way that you use `system()` to start the ngrok process in the background:

```
system("ngrok start --all -log=stdout > #{ENV['APP_ROOT']}/log/ngrok.log &")
```

Note the `&` at the end of the commandline.

I'd need more details about your runtime environment to tell precisely *which* system policy kills the orphaned ngrok process right after starting it (which OS? if Linux, is it based on systemd? how do you start rails server, from a terminal or as a system service?).

But what's happening is this:

- `system()` starts an instance of `/bin/sh` to interpret the commandline
- `/bin/sh` starts the ngrok process in the background and terminates
- ngrok is now "orphaned", meaning that its parent process `/bin/sh` is terminated, so that the ngrok process can't be `wait(2)`ed for
- depending on the environment, the terminating `/bin/sh` may kill ngrok with a SIGHUP signal
- or the OS re-parents ngrok, normally to the init-process (but this depends)

When you use the rails console or byebug, in both cases you're entering an interactive environment, which prepares "process groups", "session ids" and "controlling terminals" in a way suitable for interactive execution. These properties are inherited by child processes, like ngrok. This influences system policies regarding the handling of the orphaned background process.

When ngrok is started from rails server, these properties will be different (depending on the way rails server is started).

Here's a nice article about some of the OS mechanisms that might be involved: https://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766093-daemon-processes-in-ruby

You would probably have better success by using Ruby's `Process.spawn` to start the background process, in combination with `Process.detach` in your case. This would avoid orphaning the ngrok process.

Comment: This is what I suspected. Your insight is very pertinent. I'll try Process.spawn. Actually, what worked for me was to start a CRON job @reboot with waittime of 2 minutes. But I, and other readers of my question, are looking for a Rails-way to do this, and your insights helped a lot! Thanks!!!

Comment: Though it makes sense, an article here tells me UNIX processes are adoped by init when orphaned. I'll look further https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process